# transactions history using my secret in a live PayPal application

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a PayPal application that I just got to live mode using the developer console in PayPal
In this application I will using my PayPal application to transfer money between our users.

So far so good and the transactions are working , the money is getting passed between our users,
I just cannot see any indications or records any where in PayPal user interface.

I tried to create reports using the activity log here : https://www.paypal.com/activities
but I cannot see anything related to the transactions of our users

where I can see the records of all the transactions that are been made in my PayPal application using their Interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transaction is not between your account (but rather between users' PayPal accounts), there will be no reporting available on such transactions for you in PayPal.com account nor the transaction reporting API of that account..

To use the transaction reporting API on behalf of third parties (*without* a client id and secret from their account) requires being a PayPal partner.

If you are facilitating transactions between users, the solution is to record the successful capture in your own database for reporting purposes.